# Python craps game, while-loop issue

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a simple craps game and I am having issues.

When this code is inputted:

```
import random
def main():
    starting_money = int(input("How much do you have to gamble? : "))
    print()
    player_bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
    number_1 = (random.randint(1,6))
    number_2 = (random.randint(1,6))
    print("Dice roll 1: ", number_1)
    print("Dice roll 2: ", number_2)
    roll = number_1 + number_2
    print("Your roll: ", roll)
    rounds = input("Play again? (Y/N): ")
    while rounds != "n" and rounds == "y":
        if rounds == "n":
            print("Congratulations, you left with")
        if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
            print("You win $", player_bet, sep="")
            new_money = starting_money + player_bet
            print("You have $", new_money, " remaining.", sep="")
        elif roll == 2 or roll == 3 or roll == 12:
            new_money = starting_money - player_bet
            print("You lost $", player_bet, sep="")
            print("You have $", new_money, " remaining.", sep="")
        else:
            print("You push.")
            new_money = starting_money
            print("You have $", new_money, " remaining.", sep="")
        break
main()
```

this happens when I input "n".

```
Enter your bet: 5
Dice roll 1:  6
Dice roll 2:  6
Your roll:  12
Play again? (Y/N): n
```

and this happens when I input "y".

```
Enter your bet: 5
Dice roll 1:  2
Dice roll 2:  3
Your roll:  5
Play again? (Y/N): y
You push.
You have $10 remaining.
```

In both instances, it needs to tell the user whether or not they push, win, or lose before it asks if they want to play again. How can I accomplish this?

If I put "rounds" within the while loop, it tells me that rounds is referenced before it's assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that all of the code that tells the user whether they push, win, or lose is inside the loop, and if the user enters "n", that code never runs.  The real problem is that most of your code really should be inside the loop, including asking the user how much they want to bet and rolling the dice.

I would start by initializing the `rounds` variable to a default value of "y" so that the loop runs at least once, then don't ask the user if they want to play again until the end of the loop.  Then move all of your other code inside the loop. (Except for the "How much do you have to gamble?" part. That should probably stay outside the loop.)

This is untested, but the order of things should be something like:

```
import random

def main():
    starting_money = int(input("How much do you have to gamble? : "))
    print()

    rounds = "y"

    while rounds != "n" and rounds == "y":

        player_bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
        number_1 = (random.randint(1,6))
        number_2 = (random.randint(1,6))
        print("Dice roll 1: ", number_1)
        print("Dice roll 2: ", number_2)
        roll = number_1 + number_2
        print("Your roll: ", roll)

        if rounds == "n":
            print("Congratulations, you left with")
        if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
            print("You win $", player_bet, sep="")
            new_money = starting_money + player_bet
            print("You have $", new_money, " remaining.", sep="")
        elif roll == 2 or roll == 3 or roll == 12:
            new_money = starting_money - player_bet
            print("You lost $", player_bet, sep="")
            print("You have $", new_money, " remaining.", sep="")
        else:
            print("You push.")
            new_money = starting_money
            print("You have $", new_money, " remaining.", sep="")

        rounds = input("Play again? (Y/N): ")


main()
```

You should probably also think about ending the game if the player runs out of money.

Comment: I did all of that, but for whatever reason, the code still isn't looping.

Comment: @JCJG Get rid of the `break` statement.

Comment: Ah! that worked! Thanks a million, I think I can get the rest from here :)

Comment: @JCJG If that part is before the loop (like it is above) then it should not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot here to neaten up, but why not start with:

```
 rounds = 'y'
 while .....
   ....
   ....
   else:
     ....
   rounds = input("Play again (y/n)")
```

This way you automatically fall into the while loop after the first roll and give the user results before asking if they want to play again. The next problem you have to deal with is that within the while loop, there is no provision for placing new bets or rolling the dice again.

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to figure out how to do that :(